# Split a string by '":"' or a space after a numerical digit

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string like:

```
string = "roll:34 name:joshi ikera"
```

I want to split this string by the delimiting `:` and the space between the roll value and the name key. The output should look like this:

```
[roll, 34, name, joshi ikera]
```

I tried using:

```
string.split(/:|\d\s/)
```

but the output that I get is:

```
[roll, 3, name, joshi ikera]
```

How do I include the missing digit and just split by the space after the digit?

Comment: Would `/:|(?<=\d)\s/` work?

Comment: `string.split(/:|\s(?=.+:)/) #=> ["roll", "34", "name", "joshi ikera"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\d\s` matches and consumes the digit before a whitespace, and the consumed text is deleted by the `Regexp#split()` method. You need to use a lookaround, a lookbehind in this case, to make it a non-consuming pattern part, `/:|(?<=\d)\s/` (see [valtlai's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765945/what-regexp-rule-can-be-used-to-split-a-string-using-delimiters-and-space-af#comment84532238_48765945)). However, a more common approach in this scenario is to match 1 or more whitespace chars that are followed with 1+ word chars (if keys can only contain digits, letters and underscores) followed with `:` (see [Sagar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765945/what-regexp-rule-can-be-used-to-split-a-string-using-delimiters-and-space-af#comment84532250_48765945)).

I suggest

```
s.split(/\s+(?=\w+:)|:/)
# => roll
34
name
joshi ikera
```

Here,

- `\s+` - consumes 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?=\w+:)` - that are followed with 1+ word chars and `:`
- `|` - or
- `:` - match and consume `:`.

Or, if the keys are unique

```
s.scan(/(\w+):(.*?)(?=\w+:|\z)/).to_h
# => {"roll"=>"34 ", "name"=>"joshi ikera"}
```

Here,

- `(\w+)` - 1 or more word chars are captured into Group 1
- `:` - a colon is matched
- `(.*?)` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars are captured into Group 2 if immediately followed with
- `(?=\w+:|\z)` - either 1+ word chars and then `:` (`\w+:`) or (`|`) end of string (`\z`).